# autofac wcf integration have /basic at the end of the soap address

Tags: wcf, autofac

We had an old wcf service not using Autofac. The wsdl generated from it looks like this

```
<wsdl:service name="WebSite.Service.WebSiteService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IWebSiteService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IWebSiteService">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost/WebSiteService.svc/basic"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

However the new webservice I created with autofac wcf integration(did it following the example from autofac wcf webpage) doesn't have the word basic at the end of the soap address url (as in ...localhost/WebSiteService.svc/**basic**). It is causing some old mobile application and websites failing... I was just wondering if anyone know how I can get the word basic appearing in the soap address section?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the config entry of your WCF service. I guess providing the endpoint name to be "basic" should help you

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rajesh. There is no configuration in my web.config for this service. I registered the service with AutoFac WCF Integration and have this line in my svc file and the service works. However, I couldn't get the word basic to appear... <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebSite.Service.IWebSiteService, WebSite"  Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" %> BTW, I am running my service as part of my asp.net MVC project

Comment: From this link: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration can you follow the named service registration and see if it helps to solve your problem.